# Irrationality proof

Tags: arithmetic

Prove that $\sqrt{7-\sqrt{2}} $ is irrational
My idea is the following

$\sqrt{7-\sqrt{2}} \in\mathbb{Q}$

$w^2=7+\sqrt{2}$

$w^2-7=\sqrt{2}$ 
thus w cannot be rational 
is this correct?

edit: or maybe i can assume $\sqrt{7-\sqrt{2}} =\frac{m}{n}$ and then square both sides but the i am not sure what to do next

Comment: Because... That very last line needs a reason.

Comment: Yes. If $\sqrt{7-\sqrt 2}$ was rational then so would be $\sqrt 2$, your proof is correct. (Only the square is $7 - \sqrt 2$.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can even show $7-\sqrt2$ is irrational

as if $7-\sqrt2=a$ is rational

$$7^2+2-14\sqrt2=a^2\iff \sqrt2=(51-a^2)/(14a)$$ which is rational unlike $\sqrt2$

Comment: Wow, that's a roundabout way to prove that if $a$ is rational, then $7-a$ is rational...